# inflation calculation in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the below requirement to fulfill. How to achieve this simplistically.

There is an inflation rate table as below

```
2009, 5%
2010, 5%
2011, 5%
2012, 5%
2013, 5%
```

I need to first get

```
2009, 5%, 5
2010, 5%, 5.25        - which is 5% over 5
2011, 5%, 5.5125      - which is 5% over 5.25
2012, 5%, 5.788125    - which is 5% over 5.5125
2013, 5%, 6.07753125  - which is 5% over 5.788125
```

And then get

```
2009, 5%, 5          , 5
2010, 5%, 5.25       , 10.25            = 5.25 + 5
2011, 5%, 5.5125     , 15.7625          = 5.5125 + 10.25 and so on
2012, 5%, 5.788125   , 21.550625
2013, 5%, 6.07753125 , 27.62815625
```

Comment: Version of SQL Server? Also how many rows in the real table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this on SQLserver is to use a common table expression with recursion.
I'm not 100% sure because I can't test it here, but something along these lines as the example below. Btw I assume the rates in the table are stored as fractions, so 5% is 1.05 and 10.25% is 1.1025 etc.

```
WITH MyCompoundRates (TheYear, TheRate, CompoundRate)
AS
(
-- select one anchor record, starting point record
    SELECT
        TheYear,
        TheRate, -- I'm assuming "5%" is stored as value 1.05
        TheRate as CompoundRate
    FROM
        MyRatesTable
    WHERE
        TheYear = 2009 -- <- starting point for recursion
    UNION ALL
-- select recursive records, by linking them to a previous record
    SELECT
        r.TheYear,
        r.TheRate,
        r.TheRate * c.CompoundRate as CompoundRate -- calculate compound rate
    FROM
        MyRatesTable r
        JOIN MyCompoundRates c ON r.TheYear = c.TheYear+1 -- recursion! link a year to previous year
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT
        TheYear,
        TheRate,
        CompoundRate
FROM
    MyCompoundRates
```

Comment: Regarding testing you can use SQL Fiddle

Comment: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee62e/4/0) Didn't know about this one, it's like rubular except for SQL :D Thanks, nice find.

Comment: Guys, Thank you so much for such a quick response!! I am yet to go through the answers and will update it tomorrow.

Comment: This one is a nice one too... It took 4ms.

Comment: This one is the best answer for me. Not just does it give proper results, it also allows to select the year from which the inflation can be applied.

Answer (score 2):

Lacking a `PRODUCT()` statement, the query becomes a little more complex than would be required otherwise, but this should work well; it uses common table expressions for each step, and logarithmic sums to simulate `PRODUCT()`.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT a.year, 5 * EXP(SUM(COALESCE(LOG(b.rate),0))) rate
  FROM inflation a LEFT JOIN inflation b ON a.year > b.year
  GROUP BY a.year
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT year, rate, SUM(rate) OVER (ORDER BY year) rate_sum FROM cte1
)
SELECT * FROM cte2 ORDER BY year
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/67b4a/1).

Comment: +1 Quite concise. Has quadratic complexity but the table is small.

Comment: Guys, Thank you so much for such a quick response!! I am yet to go through the answers and will update it tomorrow.

Comment: Nice query. Short and sweet. I modified it as below to accommodate different percentages as below. It took 7ms. WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT a.year, ((a.rate-1)*100 ) * EXP(SUM(COALESCE(LOG(b.rate),0))) rate
  FROM inflation a LEFT JOIN inflation b ON a.year > b.year
  GROUP BY a.year,a.rate
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT year, rate, SUM(rate) OVER (ORDER BY year) rate_sum FROM cte1
)
SELECT * FROM cte2 ORDER BY year

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE for this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ae03/1).

```
WITH    RecursiveCTE
AS      (
        SELECT TOP 1 [Year], 
                     [Inflation], 
                     CAST(1 AS numeric(38,37)) AS Compound, 
                     CAST(5 AS numeric(38,37)) AS Value, CAST(5 AS numeric(38,10)) AS Total
        FROM Rates
        ORDER BY [Year]
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT  R.[Year], R.[Inflation], R.Compound, R.Value, R.Total
        FROM    (
                SELECT  T.*,
                         CAST(1 + R.[Inflation] * Compound AS numeric(38,37)) AS Compound,  
                         CAST(R.Value * (1 + T.Inflation) AS numeric(38,37)) AS Value,
                         CAST(R.Value * (1 + T.Inflation) AS numeric(38,37)) + R.Total AS Total,
                        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.[Year])
                FROM    Rates T
                JOIN    RecursiveCTE R
                        ON  R.[Year] < T.[Year]
                ) R
        WHERE   R.rn = 1
        )
SELECT  [Year], [Inflation], Value, Total
FROM    RecursiveCTE;
```

Comment: I didn't think of using a subquery in a recursive CTE. I like this a lot!

Comment: @David - It isn't actually needed here though! I dusted off a running totals query where the ordering column wasn't guaranteed sequential and reused it here. In this case the join on `year=year+1` per BdR's answer is presumably going to be fine.

Comment: Guys, Thank you so much for such a quick response!! I am yet to go through the answers and will update it tomorrow.

Comment: Nice to know that a CTE can be used recursively! Similarly here, if i change the interest rates in the table the results are not as expected. For example Rates were 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08 and 0.05, i would expect the resultant values to be: 5,11.3,19.091,28.61828,35.049194

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone had fun playing with this, since a bunch of answers came in at the same time.

```
DECLARE @Inflation TABLE (
    YearNum INT
    ,Inflation FLOAT
    ,LowerCalc INT
    ,AdjustedInflation FLOAT
    ,CumulativeAdjustment FLOAT);

INSERT INTO @Inflation
SELECT T.YearNum, T.Inflation, T.YearNum, T.Inflation, T.Inflation
FROM (VALUES
    (2009, 0.05),
    (2010, 0.05),
    (2011, 0.05),
    (2012, 0.05),
    (2013, 0.05)) T (YearNum, Inflation)

DECLARE @LoopBit BIT = 1;

WHILE @LoopBit = 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE I SET
        LowerCalc = IG.YearNum
        ,AdjustedInflation = I.AdjustedInflation * (1.0 + IG.Inflation)
        ,CumulativeAdjustment = I.CumulativeAdjustment + (I.AdjustedInflation * (1.0 + IG.Inflation))
    FROM @Inflation I
    LEFT JOIN @Inflation IG ON IG.YearNum = I.LowerCalc - 1
    WHERE I.LowerCalc > (SELECT MIN(YearNum) FROM @Inflation)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 SET @LoopBit = 0
END

SELECT *
FROM @Inflation
```

Comment: Guys, Thank you so much for such a quick response!! I am yet to go through the answers and will update it tomorrow.

Comment: David, Thanks for the quick response. I couldn't locate where the issue is... but when I change the rate to some other value, the result is not what was expected. For example Rates were 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08 and 0.05, i would expect the resultant values to be: 5,11.3,19.091,28.61828,35.049194

Answer (score 1):

If we have a table  Inflation (Yr INT, Rate float) , we can get the accumulated inflation as follows:

```
select i1.yr, i1.rate,  EXP(SUM(LOG(1+i2.rate))) -1 AccRate
from inflation I1
inner join inflation I2 on i1.yr >=i2.yr
group by i1.yr, i1.rate
order by 1,2
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/508b5/1/0

Comment: Wow. This is the shortest. Didn't know its that simple. So what does EXP(SUM(LOG(1+i2.rate))) do? Is it a compound interest formula?

Comment: In general, EXP(SUM(LOG(MyColumn))) will calculate the product of all MyColumn values. See it as a replacement for a PRODUCT() aggregation function which does not exist in SQL Server.

Comment: Hello @DanielB. Your query returns the rate for the entire table, if I have to modify it to specify specific periods. I have asked a question here, do you think you can help with this please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74010921/mysql-calculating-inflation-rate-between-two-month-years

Answer (score 0):

If the inflation rate is same every time as show in your example ,following formula shall help,no need of complex queries!:

```
declare @P float=5;
declare @r float =0.05;--rate = 5/100
declare @n float =1;-- 1 since compounded yearly
declare @t float = 4;--For 4 years

select @P* POWER ( (1+@r/@n),(@n*@t));
--result = 6.07753125
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use inflation concept here which we were learned in our school.

Case1-When inflation is given yearly --(not cumulative and is same through all the year).

> Look like the same case here.

So you can just use the formula .

```
Inflation at any given year=Inflation(in Year1)*(1+inflation(in year1)/100)^(n-1)
```

Also I am sure you will going to use this inflation somewhere in the calculation.

Here is the code for you

```
select 5*power((1+(5/cast(100 as float))),n);
Year1=select 5*power((1+(5/cast(100 as float))),1);--5
Year1=select 5*power((1+(5/cast(100 as float))),2);--5.5125
Year1=select 5*power((1+(5/cast(100 as float))),3);--5.788125
Year1=select 5*power((1+(5/cast(100 as float))),4);--6.07753125
Year1=select 5*power((1+(5/cast(100 as float))),5);--6.3814078125
Year1=select 5*power((1+(5/cast(100 as float))),6);--6.700478203125
```

You just need to declare a variable n.

Comment: In that case the issue is about getting cumulative value