# Calculate Inflation rates in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake SQL, I have a table with inflation factors, year on year, like this:

| Year | Inflation |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1.1 % |
| 2001 | 1.3 % |
| 2002 | -1.3 % |
| 2003 | 2.3 % |

I want to produce a table with, for every year, the total inflation from base year 2000

Thanks!

There is an old, similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667436/inflation-calculation-in-ms-sql), but I can't figure out how to adapt it

*** UPDATE ***

I tried the suggested solution, but it doesn't work:

[image: test]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL [Window Function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic), and some arithmetic trick to do that.In short, combine [SUM()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/sum), [LOG()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/log) and [EXP()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/exp) functions to get the result you wants.

The arithmetic trick behind the idea is
A X B = EXP(LOG(EXP(1),A)+LOG(EXP(1),B))

We use window-based sum() function to calculate the cumulative log(inflation rate) value up to year X. and then apply exp() to get raw cumulative inflation rate.

See the following code as example(in snowflake sql syntax, use snowflake-specific ln() function in the code):

```
select 
   record_year, 
   inflation_rate, 
   round(exp(SUM(ln(1+inflation_rate)) OVER (ORDER BY record_year)) -1,3)  as cum_inflation_rate
FROM inflation_data
```

[VERIFIED RUNNING EXAMPLE SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d4322/8)

example output:

| record_year | inflation_rate | cum_inflation_rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 0.011 | 0.011 |
| 2001 | 0.013 | 0.024 |
| 2002 | -0.013 | 0.011 |
| 2003 | 0.023 | 0.034 |

Comment: thank you @Junjie, but for some reason your code produces huge results: first year, with rate 0.014, the result is 1,009,521,342,720,310,000,000,000,000,000

Comment: Hi @ffi23, you can check my VERIFIED SQL FIDDLE LINK to see a running example for your provided data. Without further information provided, I can do a few guesses on where the problem comes from. 1. do your data store in the format of 0.014 or 1.4? 2. do you data store in one row per year format? or multiple row per year? 3. why the data starts from 1960, it sounds like casting null value to datetime format and return earliest possible time (1960-xx-xxx)?

Comment: Hi @ffi23, I found out the issue. in snowflake log() function, the parameter order (base, expr) is different from most of other DB parameter order(expr, base). I updated the query in the answer to be for snowflake log() function format, a.k.a. log(exp(1),1+inflation_rate). Have another try.

Comment: @Junjie A simpler way would be to just use [LN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ln)

Comment: Hi @LukaszSzozda, that's right. I use log() in case any one want to use the logic in other DB. Update the query to use ln() instead of log(exp(1),) for this use case.

Comment: that's great thank you, it works as expected now